# Issues with recording donation refunds

Tags: contributions

If a donor makes a credit card donation that is later reversed/refunded, what is the best way to record this? Just delete the gift?  Can you record a negative gift amount to offset the refund?

Answer (score 2):

We go to the Contribution > Edit Contribution, change Contribution Status to Refunded. It is one of the drop-down options for Contribution Status.

[image]